# Weird background shape of floating action button when pressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, floating-action-button

I am having a hard time finding out why this docked floating action button behaves like this. When I press the floating action button, it shows a weird background shape when pressed.

[image]

Code:

```
floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 155),
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 100,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() {_currentIndex=4;}),
              child: Tab(
                icon: Image.asset('images/scan.png'),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

Comment: Check for `splashRadius` parameter.

Comment: @esentis , thanks for your response! where I will get the 'splashRadius' parameter? I am only getting 'splashColor' parameter. Setting 'splashColor' to '.transparent' does not change anything.

Comment: That's because of the `Tab` style aswell.

Comment: There is no point of the `Tab` just remove it.

Comment: You are right, I have removed `Tab` but sadly it doe not solve the problem.